# Can `Jam` be used as an alternative to GNU Make with autoconf?

Tags: windows, linux, makefile, mingw, autotools

As it is stated on [the FT Jam page at freetype.org](http://www.freetype.org/jam/index.html):

> Jam is a small open-source build tool that can be used as a replacement for Make. Even though Jam is a lot simpler to use than Make, it is far more powerful and easy to master. It already works on a large variety of platforms (Unix, Windows, OS/2, VMS, MacOS, BeOS, etc.), it is trivial to port, and its design is sufficiently clear to allow any average programmer to extend it with advanced features at will.

Are there any ways to substitute `make` for `jam` to make autoconf-based projects in MinGW / MSYS to build faster?

Answer (score 1):

No. Autoconf relies on a Unix shell and associated utilities. It might be hacked to generate jam files, but the configure step *is* autotools. If you just have a plain makefile, you might as well just use mingw32-make and ditch autotools completely if possible.